# How to unit test sendAccessibilityEvent(...) on Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, accessibility

I'm trying to send `sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)` to a view, and it's working fine when I have talkback enabled on my device, but I need to write a unit test for that line.

I have tried with `view.isAccessibilityFocused` but this property is always false, I suspect because I don't have any accessibility service running on the test.

I'm using Roboelectric.

Answer (score 0):

```
final List<Integer> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
view
    .setAccessibilityDelegate(
        new AccessibilityDelegate() {
          @Override
          public void sendAccessibilityEvent(@NonNull View host, int eventType) {
            eventList.add(eventType);
            super.sendAccessibilityEvent(host, eventType);
          }
        });

assertThat(eventList).contains(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
```

Run the view.setAccessibilityDelegate before running the unit test you want to perform.

Thats what works for me.